# including Subform primary key into main form foreign key

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

The purpose of the main form that I have created is to allow my fellow co-workers to be able to have one place where they can enter in the information about various complaints we get. We have three types of complaints, each having their own tables, of which one is a subform in my main form. The primary key of the table of the subform is entered in by the user. I haven't found a way to have that primary key be added to the record that is produced for that entry. I am working with MS Access 2007 and the only code that came close to doing what I wanted was:

```
    Private Sub Booking_Reference_Number_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
     If Not IsNull(Form![Booking Reference Number]!PK_Booking_Ref_Number) Then
      Dim mydb As Database
      Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

      Set mydb = CurrentDb()
      Set rst = mydb.OpenRecordset("Incident_Report")

      rst.AddNew
      rst![FK_Booking_Ref_Number] = Form![Booking Reference Number]!PK_Booking_Ref_Number
      rst.Update

      Set rst = Nothing
      Set mydb = Nothing

     End If
    End Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: And what is the question? What happens when code executes - error message, wrong results, nothing? I don't understand data structure nor the process you are trying to code. Why do you need code to create record? Why not bound forms?

Comment: Having the fields linked through the parent child link doesn't fill the foreign key with the value of the primary key for the record that's relevant. Having the fields be in a one-to-many relationship doesn't seem to work either. My understanding that since the fields are from another table, it has to be in a subform. I'm trying to insure that my users only worry about filling out the information on the main form. I would like help with figuring out a code that will accomplish this for me.

Comment: If these tables are intended to have parent/child relationship and the subform container control Master/Child LInks properties are set then the PK from main record will populate the FK field in the subform as soon as any other data is input to subform record. Why would there not be any data for users to input on subform? Sounds like very unusual situation.

Comment: The PK is in the subform and the FK is in the main form. I set this up so that the record in the table for the subform is created while filling out the main form

Comment: That's totally backwards to conventional structure and really can't envision any situation where that is practical.

Comment: The main form table has the complaint information and type of customer the complaint involved, which we decided to have three types. The three types of customers have their own tables, and I would like the main form to either allow the PK to be typed in to start a new entry or allow the other fields in the table to be filled out, of course with confirming the entered PKs are unique.

Comment: Why 3 tables? If the fields are all the same should be 1 table with an additional field CustType. Possibly your subform should really be a combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the *default value* of the FK field (on the subform) to be the name of the PK on the main form?  For example - [MainForm]![ControlName]

Comment: Would that work the opposite way? My Subform has the PK and the Main Form table has the FK

Comment: Won't work. Subform loads before the main form, I know, weird but true. And really shouldn't be necessary with Master/Child Links properties of subform container.

Comment: I'll play around with a simple main and sub forms to see if there's a way for the PK in the sub form table gets included in the table of the main form, since this sounds like the core of my issue. Even though the table for the code initially posted can be included in the main form table, I have another that shouldn't be.

Comment: And the reverse would require user to select record on subform first then begin entry on main form.